# Can't start apache2 server

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm getting the following error message while starting apache2 server:

> $ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start  * Starting
>   web server apache2
>   (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address
>   0.0.0.0:443 no listening sockets available, shutting down Unable to open logs Action 'start' failed. The Apache error log may have more
>   information.
>                                                                                                                                 [fail]

Here is the output of **sudo netstat -lntup**:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:28017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      941/mongod
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1355/dnsmasq
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      687/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      854/cupsd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      941/mongod
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      687/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      854/cupsd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22543           0.0.0.0:*                           1049/dhclient
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           1355/dnsmasq
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           1049/dhclient
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:46027           0.0.0.0:*                           901/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           901/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::38743                :::*                                901/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::27403                :::*                                1049/dhclient
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                901/avahi-daemon: r
```

Anyone knows why and how it should be fixed?

Thanks!!!

Comment: instead of 'start' try 'restart'

Comment: Your `netstat` isn't showing any thing on :443.  Can you try `sudo ss -ln` and `sudo lsof -inP`?  Also, make sure that you have freespace available. (`df -h`)

Comment: "The Apache error log may have more information. [fail]" -- Have you looked in the Apache error log, by chance?

Comment: No 443 port shown by sudo ss -ln as well.
Free space is ok (more then enough).
sudo lsof -inP ? does not work:
sudo lsof -inP ?
lsof: unknown protocol name (nP) in: -i nP
lsof 4.86

Comment: Try a reboot, yet? Every thing shows you don't have a process listening on 443.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache gives this same error message when you have two `Listen` directives that target the same IP/port combination.  The first one succeeds without error, the second one finds that something is already listening on that port and aborts.

It's not uncommon to find these directives in different files, such as vhost files or top-level files such as `ports.conf` or `ssl.conf`.

You can find them with `grep -r Listen /etc/apache2` or `grep -r Listen /etc/httpd` depending on whether you are using a Debian-based distro or a RedHat-based distro.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem was in /etc/apache2/ports.conf indeed.

Answer (score 2):

I have had success in this situation by running the following:

```
/usr/bin/pkill apache2 && /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

The purpose is to kill any lingering apache processes (the "pkill"), and then start apache

Comment: Apache restart/stop does not guarantee all processes get killed.  Some apache processes have become non-responsive and sometimes require a non "nice" kill signal to terminate (i.e. -9).

Comment: Unfortunately, I got the same error message again.

Answer (score 1):

port Apache is trying to use is already in use, use command `sudo netstat -lntup` and look for  :443, you will find a entry.  What ever is listening to port 443 stop that and try starting apache again and that should do the trick.

Comment: Strange - nobody's listening to port 443.
It must be something else... :(

Comment: paste the output of sudo netstat -lntup here please

Comment: Sure. I copy-pasted that output to the question body.

Comment: Thanks, yeah you are right nothing on port 443, did you check the apache error logs, can we see what they have to say about this.

Comment: Last errors were from one hour ago, here they are:
[Sat Feb 02 01:34:00 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] access to /var/www/svn failed, reason: SSL connection required
[Sat Feb 02 01:37:11 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Feb 02 01:42:09 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down

Comment: apparently, there are SSL specific settings in more than one file which is causing this issue